# Google Sheets Clock Cycle Counter - Increment value only on TRUE value in another cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to increase the numeric value of a cell `output`, based on the contents of another cell `input` that will contain a binary value. I'd like to do this without using scripts.

Cell B5 is going to alternate between TRUE and FALSE. When B5 changes from FALSE to TRUE I want B6 to increment by 1.

The goal I'm trying to achieve could be thought of as a clock cycle counter with `output` being the display of completed cycles and `input` alternating between 0 and 1 as the clocking signal.

The overall goal is to run a trigger when B6 `output`'s value is changed.

- B1 is the total distance elapsed
- B2 is the distance interval between scheduling services
- B3 is manually updated with the current value of B1 when the last service was performed. This may not be evenly divisible by B2; it could happen before or after the desired interval elapses.
- B4 Is the distance remaining until the next service should be scheduled B3 + B2 - B1
- B5 `input` is FALSE when (B2 + B3) < B1 and TRUE when (B2 + B3) >= B1

[image]

The document is the page `Service` in the linked spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XxwyJWZ7PdvjOg4vz8AKAfbvd44TmNQuBVR571OnXfQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Added sheet link to the question, thanks :)

Comment: what is your question exactly? can you provide some examle and show the desired result? it's not clear at all what you are after

Comment: Cell B5 is going to alternate between TRUE and FALSE. When B5 changes from FALSE to TRUE I want B6 to increment by 1. All it needs to do is count how many times B5 has changed from FALSE to TRUE and display that value in cell B6.

Comment: simple `=IF(B5=TRUE, 1, 0)` would do with instant changes but I guess you want to count changes across the time, is that correct? in that case you will need a script which will "archive" B5 Trues as ones and then sum them into B6

Comment: Ah thanks, I was hoping to get away without using script so it would work on mobile. It sounds like I might have to use scripts and run on desktop only.